# why sbt-assembly failed to auto detect main class?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a Boot object with below definition

```
object Boot extends App with xxxService {}
```

And add below lines in plugins.sbt to enable sbt-assembly

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
```

then run this command to build up the whole project:

```
sbt clean compile assembly
```

In the genearted jar META-INF/MAINFEST.MF file, it does not have Main-Class generated, if I specify main class in build.sbt like `mainClass in assembly := Some("com.XXX.Boot")`, it worked.

My sbt version is 1.3.2, jvm is zulu8, scala is 2.12.13

From [enter link description here](https://index.scala-lang.org/sbt/sbt-assembly/sbt-assembly/0.14.4?target=_2.10_0.13) it says, sbt-assembly will autodetect main class, then how does my example failed?

Answer (score 0):

I update sbt-assembly into below

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "1.2.0")
```

it can auto detect the main class without specify in build.sbt...

I guess this is might be related with sbt and scala verion...
my colleague can run the config in the question correctly...